# instead of showing information about the tags ('li' - tags) it throws the AttributeError

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

code

```
  1 main = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "global-nav__nav")))

  2 lists = main.find_elements_by_class_name("global-nav__primary-items")

  3 my_network = lists.get_property('li')[0].keys()

  4 my_network
```

error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_property'

Please suggest some more information regarding list info extraction using selenium

Comment: edit your question ("tages", "tage"). Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Obviously `lists` is an object of built-in type `list`. If you want to apply `get_property` you need to do something like `lists[0].get_property(...)`. But since there is not enough info in your question this might not solve your problem

Comment: Are you skipping code or have you updated the error?   line 3 create `lists`, line 4 is `lists`  - but your error says `list`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
lists = main.find_elements_by_class_name("global-nav__primary-items")
```

Is returning all elements that match that identifier. You're getting a list.

Then, when you do this:

```
my_network = lists.
```

You're not accessing the element, your accessing the list itself.

You can do:

```
my_network = lists[0].get_property('li')[0].keys()
```

where `[0]` is the a the first item within the list (and assuming the rest of your line works... at a glance i'm not sure about the rest of it `.get_property('li')[0].keys()`)

Or you can iterate through all:

```
for x in lists
    print(x.text) # do your action here
```

or, if there is only 1 element that matches your class, you can use:

```
main.find_element_by_class_name("global-nav__primary-items")
```

note this is `find_element...` vs `find_elements...`
This will not return a list but a single we element.

If you can share the html code around your problem, someone can typically help you with identifies and code.